# Аналог SqlBulkCopy для SQLite

Tags: sqlite3, c#, ado.net

Сейчас мы переходим с Microsoft SQL Server на SQLite. У нас используется класс `SqlBulkCopy` для массовой вставки данных в БД SQL Server. Есть ли аналогичный инструмент для SQLite?

Answer (score 1):

Можно посмотреть тут: [SQLite Bulk Insert In C#/.NET](http://procbits.com/2009/09/08/sqlite-bulk-insert/). В комментах пишут, что 200 тыс записей до 3 секунд.

Comment: Я не знаю, кто там пишет в комментах, этот код не компилируется.